# How can I create an SVG checkbox?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make a simple checkbox using an svg.

It doesn't have to be animated nor anything. I just want it to change the fill color when checked. As simple as that.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>

        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
        svg input:checked  {
            fill:yellow;
        }

        .my-image:hover {
            background-color:green;
            fill:red;
        }

        .my-image input:checked {
            fill:red;
        }

        </style>
    </header>

    <body>

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked/>
            <svg class = "my-image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="17"
            height="16" viewBox="0 0 17 16">
            <path d="M8.500,0.000 L11.301,5.028 L16.999,6.112 L13.033,10.302 L13.753,16.000 L8.500,13.561 L3.247,16.000 L3.967,10.302 L0.001,6.112 L5.699,5.028 L8.500,0.000"
            class="cls-1" />
            </svg>

        </label>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="application/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is driving me absolutely crazy. The svg even has a red background that I don't know where it comes from.

[image]

I watched a lot of tutorials, read a lot and tried a lot of examples. None of them worked.

I just need a simple checkbox using svgs. Can you please help me out?

Also, I'm new to CSS and HTML. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.my-image input:checked` won't work this way, cause the `input` isn't a child element of `.my-image` and even if, the `fill: red` wouldn't be used for your image.

You could do something like this to achieve what you are trying:

```
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .my-image {
        fill:red;
  }
```

I created a fiddle where you can check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/uvt5zqr9/

In this fiddle the background isn't red, i guess maybe you have something in your `app.css` which causes the red background.

Comment: Thanks man. It works perfectly! I can't believe it was that simple.